# How do you set up a file association with a click-once application?

Tags: c#, clickonce, file-association

I have a click-once application.

I have an associated file that I store the application's data in.

When a user clicks on one of these files I want it to open the click-once app and load the file.

I can set up the file association in the publish, the icon and name is correctly set. Clicking on the file opens the application, but the application doesn't seem to be passed the path to the file - the command arguments are empty.

How do I get it so that the path to the file is passed to the application?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When using Click Once, arguments are not passed in on the command line, they are passed in through the Click Once deployment system:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData
```

For example, in your Program.cs file:

```
foreach (string commandLineFile in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData)
{
    MessageBox.Show( string.Format("Command Line File: {0}", commandLineFile) );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Additionally, I have found that the ActivationData also may be null, so one should check for that.

Comment: ActivationArguments can also be null.